# Deploying web-application on apache2 server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have installed/setup PHP5 and Apache2 server on Ubuntu and trying to deploy a dummy project on it.

[image]

The server is up and running.but the URL `http://localhost/DemoWebApp` gives me

`Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong or how do I set it up correctly?

### Edit:

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: do you have files in DemoWebApp ?

Comment: Yes, I do have. Edited my post and added screenshot for project structure.

Comment: What actually helped me was to give the `html` folder permission, as I noticed it was green shaded (which is 777 right?). thank you

Answer (score 2):

move DemoWebApp into html folder and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Set `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` to `/var/www` or move DemoApp folder to `/var/www/html`

Comment: I don't see any directory `httpd` under `etc`.

Comment: ahh, ubuntu I guess it is named `apache2`, or run `find /etc -iname 'httpd.conf'`

Comment: I figured out that the file which needs to be edited is `000-default.conf` which is available under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have ubuntu handy - 
httpd -S 
see if you get the virtual host listed.

I am assuming the localhost (no directory)- does what it should

It looks like your directory is not configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines inside the httpd.conf file

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

It is just to set the handler for the php files.
make sure that in this file you have enabled PHP Module  i.e.

```
LoadModule php5_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have not configured the DemoApp properly. Check the files inside DemoApp folder. Also make sure that your app is running on **Port 80.**  Because if the app is running at some other port  ( and not the default port 80), then this might occur.

Once everything is set, restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**EDIT** (After seeing your files in the DemoApp folder)
Another problem could be index.php not being loading/ recognized by server. Check in `httpd.conf`, (sometimes just index.html will be recognized as default index file.). If it is not set to be the default index file, add the following lines in httpd.conf

```
<Directory /DemoApp>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Another approach is create a `.htaccess` file and add the below line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```